# Not getting session data in custom helper file - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

Actually, I am trying to define a constant and setting value from the session
in a custom helper added using Helper Service Provider. But not getting the session data in here.

I have added a Helper using Helper Service Provider, It's working fine.
But trying to get the session value.

In **HelperServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register()
{ 
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
        require_once($filename);
    }
}
```

And in **ERPHelper.php** in App/Helpers folder, I am trying to get the session data.  But not getting the session value.

$company = session('company');

Comment: Probably when the Application register your helper the session is not even started, FYI session starts in a middleware.

Comment: @dparoli How can I register the helper after the session started? Do you suggest me any way to do that.

Comment: Best practice is to define helper function and classes in a helper file, I wouldnt assign anythig directly in the file but you can access session inside helper functions. if you want to get session data and set constant or config values the best place is IMHO to write a middleware and be sure it is called after StartSessionMiddleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often down to the middleware. If you're setting the `company` session value under the `web` middleware, you might not be able to retrieve this is in a helper function registered by the service provider.

Also, out of interest, why are you setting this in a constant? It seems odd to me to use a the session helper to retrieve a value and then set it in a constant. A constant should probably not be used in this way but also you are adding an additional layer of abstraction. Why not just call `session('company')` as and when you need it?

I load in a helper `Bootstrap.php` via the `composer.json` file in the `autoload` section:

```
 "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/Bootstrap.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ]
 },
```

Then in the `Bootstrap.php` you could run your glob to load the relevant files.

That said, this still might not help because you're outside the web middleware. Can you not pass the session value to your helper function?

```
// Helper function.
function myErpHelper($companySessionValue) {
    // My code here...
}

// Calling the helper function.
myErpHelper(session('company'));
```

Comment: adding in constant is not so important, actually, I need the session data in this helper. Is there any data to get the session data in this file.